# No internet connection on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, networking, server

I have an Ubuntu server and I cannot get Internet connection over this. The IP,subnet,gateway and the 2 DNS servers that I have been given is standard addresses that I must put into. 
I will give details of this:

1)

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

returns

```
Network is unreachable
```

2)

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

is set to

```
#The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#The primary network interface
#auto eth0 <-- this is a comment
iface eth0 inet static
address "My_static_ip_here"
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway  "My_Gateway_here"
```

3)

```
sudo nano /etc/resolve.conf
```

is set to

```
nameserver "My_DNS_server_1_here"
nameserver "My_DNS_server_2_here"
```

Finally, `ifconfig`

returns 127.0.0.1 address and a subnet 255.0.0.0 ofcourse on **lo**
I cannot give detailed ifconfig here because of the limitations that I got.
PS: This is a virtual machine that I am using.
PS2: I tried to auto-dhcp it with iface eth0 inet dhcp but during the networking restart it kept loading and loading forever, so that does not work and I want to give this static IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Place the DNS servers in `/etc/network/interfaces`, not in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Add this line at the bottom of your static configurations

```
dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 #OpenDNS' servers as example
```

Then run these commands in the terminal to restart the interface.

```
sudo su

ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0
```

Hope this works!

Comment: This works fine! Thanks very much. And I have thought about that and I said "nah, it will not be a difference". Greetings!

Answer (score 4):

Setting aside the that this is a VM and if hypervisor is setup correctly to forward packets from this VM.

Please uncomment `#auto eth0 <-- this is a comment` and issue a network service restart:
`sudo service network restart`

This tells the system to bring the interface up automatically at boot.

Else you can issue the command

`sudo ifconfig eth0 up` at each boot.

Comment: Ok, I did. I thought it was wrong but I had dhcp instead of static. Now I get in /etc/init.d/networking restart again, but ping google.com returns unknown host. That is my issue. Can you help me out more on this? Thanks for the concern.

Comment: @George: You should restart network service like this: sudo service networking restart

Comment: Does ping 8.8.8.8 work now, if yes then its a DNS issue now.

Comment: Thanks guys. It is solved now. Thanks for your immediate answers.